# How to keep my scraping program continue to scrape indefinitely?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, openpyxl

I am new to python. I created a program that takes news from google news and stores it in an excel notebook. I was wondering how I could keep this program going indefinitely and continue to record news live? For example, it would continue to store information in the excel sheet for tomorrow, the day after, etc. My code is below. Thank you very much. I was also thinking of maybe incorporating mysql into this and using it as a database, but I am not 100% sure how to do that yet.

```html
# Web Scraping App to find Top Stories

# Importing Python Libraries
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen
from openpyxl import Workbook


# Initializing the website in rss format
url ="https://news.google.com/news/rss"

# Sending request to open the website
urlopener=urlopen(url)

# Reading the website and setting it to a variable
xml =urlopener.read()

# Closing the function
urlopener.close()

# Parsing the xml page using Beautiful Soup
souped_page = soup(xml, 'xml')
# Finding the 'item' or title of the news
news_list = souped_page.findAll('item')

# Creating empty lists to store information
titlelist =[]
linklist = []
datelist = []

# Appending all the required information to the corresponding list
for news in news_list:
    titlelist.append(news.title.text)
    linklist.append(news.link.text)
    datelist.append(news.pubDate.text)

# Creating an excel document for the news
workbook = Workbook()
sheet = workbook.active

# Initializing variables to write to the excel document
count = 2
listindex1 = 0

# Initializing titles for the document
sheet['A1'].value = 'News'
sheet['B1'].value = 'News_Link'
sheet['C1'].value = 'Time_of_News'

# Iterating through each item in the list
for title in titlelist:
        sheet['A'+ str(count)].value = titlelist[listindex1]
        sheet['B' + str(count)].value = linklist[listindex1]
        sheet['C' + str(count)].value = datelist[listindex1]
        count+=1
        listindex1+=1

# Saving the information
workbook.save(filename='top_news_formatted.xlsx')
```

Comment: I would add to @Jem 's answer that you can also do something to launch your code automatically as soon as you computer reboots. Depending on your OS, the way to do is different, and it may require some coding, but it is very rewarding and would avoid adding something to your mental todo list.

Comment: Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to do this would be to add a while statement and wait a certain time before doing the loop again.

```
import time

while True:
    # your code

    # wait 86400 seconds which is exactly one day
    time.sleep(86400)
```

Answer (score 0):

A rather practical solution would be to run this python file every time your PC reboots. If your PC runs continuously, then the answer given by [Jem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12581188/jem) would suffice.

To do so in Windows, just add a shortcut of your file into the startup folder (if you don't know where is your startup folder, just open run and enter **shell:startup**,  it will take you to your startup folder.